# Gave up waiting for root file system device

Tags: debian, boot, startup, busybox, uuid

Here's what it says when I first turn on my computer: `BusyBox v1.30.1 (Debian 1 :1.30.1-4) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands`. I watched a youtube video expecting it to work, but instead when I used exit this is what pulled up:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) 
ALERT! UUID=d63751a9-a3cc-46c7-99ee-1d6f0abcfede does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

I saw somewhere that someone used `blkid` for a similar problem, and when I do that, this pulls up

```
/dev/sda2: UUID= "xxxx" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="bc0af638-02"
```

Does anybody have any tips or can anyone walk me through the problems please? Is it unfixable or not.

Comment: Has this computer ever worked? If the `blkid` output that you report is complete, the root partition has disappeared somehow. There are tools and methods to recreate deleted partitions, since the partition **table** is often the only thing that was modified, and the partition **content** (i.e. the root filesystem, in your case) still exists on the disk, but has to be found. It should not be too hard to find instructions on the internet.

Comment: @berndbausch yes it has worked before and stopped working after a power outage.

Comment: My guess is that the power outage broke the partition table. I have no experience finding deleted partitions. Perhaps somebody else will present an idea, or your internet search is successful. If the disk doesn't contain much useful data, perhaps a re-installation is the best approach.